# Некорректно читаются данные из файла

Tags: c++, fstream

Есть код, который читает данные из текстового файла и выводит их на экран и в другой файл.

Вот код:

```
db_file.open(File_Zap.c_str(), ios::in); //объявлен чуть ранее экземпляр класса fstream
                    if (!db_file.is_open())  {
                                cerr << "\n Open ERROR!";
                                break;
                        } else {
                        // Вывод на экран 
                            cout << "\n\t--------- Informations ---------" << endl;
                        // Запись такой же информации в текстовый файл fout
                            fout << "\n\t--------- Informations ---------" << endl;

                            db_file.seekg(0, ios::end);       // выясняем размер файла
                            len = db_file.tellg();            // и записываем его в переменную
                            kol = len/size;                   // чтобы узнать количество записанных данных.
                            selection = new TZap[kol];
                            db_file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
                             while(!db_file.eof())
                                {
                                   readData(db_file, selection[counter]);
                                   Out(fout, selection[counter]);
                                   counter++;
                                }
                            db_file.close();      
                            delete []selection;

//...
void Out(ofstream & fout, TZap z)
{
     cout << "\n ФИО – " << z.FIO 
     << "\n Дата рождения – " << z.dateOfBirth
     << "\n Группа – " << z.group
     << "\n Оценка по физике – " << z.notes.fiz
     << "\n Оценка по математике – " << z.notes.math
     << "\n Оценка по информатике – " << z.notes.cs
     << "\n Оценка по химии – " << z.notes.chem
     << "\n Средний балл – " << z.s_ball
     << endl;

     fout << "\n ФИО – " << z.FIO 
     << "\n Дата рождения – " << z.dateOfBirth
     << "\n Группа – " << z.group
     << "\n Оценка по физике – " << z.notes.fiz
     << "\n Оценка по математике – " << z.notes.math
     << "\n Оценка по информатике – " << z.notes.cs
     << "\n Оценка по химии – " << z.notes.chem
     << "\n Средний балл – " << z.s_ball
     << endl;
}

void calcGreatPointAverage(TZap* obj) {
    obj->s_ball = (obj->notes.chem + obj->notes.cs + obj->notes.math + obj->notes.fiz) / 4;
}

void readData(fstream & fs, TZap & object) {
    fs.getline(Zap.FIO, FIO_SIZE);
    fs.getline(Zap.dateOfBirth, BDAY_SIZE);
    fs.getline(Zap.group, GROUP_SIZE);
    fs >> object.notes.fiz
       >> object.notes.math
       >> object.notes.cs 
       >> object.notes.chem

      >> object.s_ball;
}
```

Структура файла `db_file` получается такая:

```
Иванов И.И.
12.12.1990
123230
1  2  3  4  2
```

При запуске программы в лог пишется какой-то мусор: куски системного PATH, алфавит, большие цифры и типа того. В чём тут может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
db_file.seekg(0, ios::end);
```

После этого оператора указатель чтения установится в конец файла и `db_file.eof()` вернёт `true`. Возвращайте указатель в начало перед чтением, используя

```
db_file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

В Вашем случае чтение не выполнится никогда и в переменной будет мусор.

Comment: Да, в этом и была проблема. Спасибо. Но вот откуда в выводе оказалась переменная среды PATH? Может, у вас есть идеи? Чей это баг и куда репортить?

Comment: PATH считался из блока системных переменных, который присутствует у любой запущенной программы. Или из стека. Или из прилетевшего с Альфы Центавра фотона. Баг в Вашей программе и заключается он в неинициализированных переменных. Неинициализированная переменная влечёт неопределённое поведение. Считаться может что угодно и откуда угодно. Репортить баг себе, на свой почтовый адрес.

Comment: Спасибо. Посыпаю голову пеплом.

Comment: Не совсем помогло. В выводе остался мусор, но хотя бы появилась инфа из файла. Вместо файла, как я понимаю, читается вся память, выделенная процессу.